# Bound for the degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a perfect field and let $f\in K[x]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial of degree $n$.
Denote by $\alpha,\beta$ two distinct roots of $f$. 
Is the following bound true?
$$
[K(\alpha-\beta):K]\geq \frac n2
$$
If not, does someone know a similar bound (if it exists)?

Comment: A general result is that $\alpha-\beta$ generates all of $K(\alpha,\beta)$ unless $\alpha-\beta=\alpha'-\beta'$ for some zeros $\alpha'\neq\alpha$ and $\beta'\neq\beta$ of $f$. This forces $[K(\alpha-\beta):K]\ge n$ often enough.

Comment: Yes, it's the proof of the primitive element.

Comment: Trying to come up with a characteristic zero example :-( If you think about it inside the splitting field of $f$, you see that $\alpha-\beta$ needs a very large stabilizer inside the Galois group.

Comment: Should I write another question in order to obtain a conterexample in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @Joel92, yes I think that would be best. Oh and no consecutive roots this time, so that's out ...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844835/degree-of-the-differents-of-two-roots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bound does not hold. Consider the Artin-Schreier polynomial, $$f(X)=X^p-X+1\in\mathbb{F}_p[X]$$

Note that $f(\alpha)=0\implies f(\alpha+1)=0$. Take $\beta=\alpha+1$ to obtain a contradiction to the proposed bound.

Comment: Is there a counterexample in $\mathbb Q$? I can't find one.