# Degree of the difference of two roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f\in \mathbb Q[x]$ be an irreducible monic polynomial of degree $n$ and let $\alpha,\beta\in \overline{\mathbb Q}$ be two distinct roots of $f$.
Is it possible to find a lower bound on the degree of $\alpha-\beta$?
By heart, my claim is that
$$
[\mathbb Q(\alpha-\beta):\mathbb Q]\geq \frac n2
$$
The original question [Bound for the degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844708/bound-for-the-degree) concerned the same claim for arbitrary fields.
If the claim is false, can someone find a bound, if it exists?

Comment: At least a start: Are you aware of the fact that $\alpha - \beta \notin \mathbb Q$? This is easy to show and gives you the the bound $\geq 2$.

Comment: Just adding that equality is possible.

Comment: @Hmm Have you got an example with equality, when $n$ has an odd prime factor?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, for $\alpha-\beta$, I do not. For $\alpha+\beta$ I do, consider the cyclotomic fields.

Comment: Sure, the sum is easier. For some reason I was also thinking about cyclotomic fields :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen :) But even the difference is not too bad. It's just $i\text {sin}\biggr(\dfrac{2\pi}{n}\biggl)$, whose degree is, if I'm not mistaken, is $\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{2}$ if $(n,8)=4$. Let me check..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that $\alpha-\beta$ is algebraic of degree $<n/2$.

As an example I proffer
$$
\alpha=\sqrt5+\sqrt3+\sqrt2,\quad\beta=\sqrt5+\sqrt3-\sqrt2.
$$
Here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both conjugate primitive elements of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5,\sqrt3,\sqrt2)$ - [a degree eight extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1313897/11619). Yet $\alpha-\beta=2\sqrt2$ is a root of a quadratic.

---

It is hopefully clear how to extend the above example to a case where $f(x)$ has degree $2^\ell$ for arbitrary positive integer $\ell$ such that $\alpha-\beta$ generates a quadratic extension only.

---

As MooS pointed out, $\alpha-\beta$ cannot be rational. So $[\Bbb{Q}(\alpha-\beta):\Bbb{Q}]=2$ is as low as it can go. For the sake of completeness let me recap an argument. If $\alpha-\beta=q\in\Bbb{Q}$, then
$\beta=\alpha-q$. Therefore $\alpha$ is a zero of two monic polynomials with rational coefficients, $f(x)$ and $f(x+q)$. Because we are in characteristic zero $f(x)$ and $f(x+q)$ are distinct (look at the coefficients of degree $n-1$ terms). Therefore their greatest common divisor has a lower degree, and must be non-trivial given that it has $\alpha$ as a root.

---

See [the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1844708/11619) to learn why the assumption about characteristic zero is essential.

Comment: Just adding a link to a proof of the fact that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are conjugates- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313897/minimal-polynomial-of-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt5. Hope you do not mind...

Comment: Of course, not @Hmm. I was about to start looking for one.

Comment: For a proof of conjugacy of sums of signed square roots of primes see [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/93453/11619) and the material linked to there.