# What is wrong with this proof that a polynomial is solvable by radicals?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, solvable-groups

We consider
$$x^5 - x + 5 \in \mathbb{Q}[x].$$

I'm pretty sure that this polynomial is NOT solvable by radicals since its Galois group is isomorphic to $S_5$ (see [my question from yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4826985/305862)).

However, my teacher is pretty sure that it IS solvable by radicals, and he proved it by seeing that its Galois group is isomorphic to $D_5$ (and I think it's not).

He considers the roots of the polynomial $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \overline{\alpha_2}, \alpha_3, \overline{\alpha_3}$, with $\alpha_1 \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha_2, \alpha_3 \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$.
These roots form a regular pentagon, and since two pairs of roots are conjugate, we can consider the rotation $a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$ and the permutation $b = (2, 5)(3, 4)$, which generate
$$D_5 = \left\langle a, b \mid a^5 = 1 = b^2, ba = a^{-1}b \right\rangle.$$

So then he saw that $D_5$ is solvable by radicals and deduced that the polynomial is solvable by radicals too.

I don't really understand at all what he does, so I am not able to say what is wrong with it… Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: The Galois group certainly contains a $5$-cycle, and complex conjugation induces a permutation of consisting of two transpositions, like $(2,5)(3,4)$, but that does not prove that these are the only types of permutations, it proves only that the order of the Galois group is at least $10$. In fact it is the whole of $S_5$.

Comment: @DerekHolt That's right!!! But how could we prove that there are more types of permutations?

Comment: Compare with the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637796/galois-group-of-x5-x-1-over-bbb-q).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you so much!

Comment: The roots **do not** form a regular pentagon.  A polynomial whose roots form a regular pentagon with one real root and the others complex conjugates would be $$(x-a)^5 - b^5 = x^{5}-5 a \,x^{4}+10 a^{2} x^{3}-10 a^{3} x^{2}+5 a^{4} x -a^{5}-b^{5}$$

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes you're right, I'm editing it!

Comment: @JeanMarie Oooh thank you!! :D

Comment: @RobertIsrael I don't know what theorem is used to justify it but if you write the polynomial in [Wolfram Alpha](https://wolframalpha.com) then you'll see that the roots form a regular pentagon.

Comment: Reducing modulo 2 gives a product of degree 2 and 3. By a theorem of Dedekind, the Galois group thus must contain an element that is a produict of a 2-cycle and 3-cycle.

Comment: @ahulpke ... under the condition that the discriminant of the polynomial is not dividable by 2 (= odd) which is the case.

Comment: [Another case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3414987/11619) where one may jump to incorrect conclusions about the shape of the set of roots, if one doesn't do the arithmetic carefully enough (as in Jean Marie's nice answer) :-)

Comment: @JeanMarie About ahulpke's argument: The discriminant condition is not necessary, when, after reduction modulo a prime, there are no repeated factors. I think those two conditions are actually equivalent, but need to check :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the pentagon formed by the roots of

$$x^5-x+5=0 \tag{1}$$

is neither regular nor centered in $0$ (one can be fooled by the fact that the axes haven't necessarily the same length if it is not explicitly asked).

[image]

One can check it on the approximate values of the roots, which are :

$$\begin{cases}r_1&\approx&-1.4519\\r_2&\approx&-0.36823+1.3592i\\r_3&=&\overline{r_2}\\r_4&\approx&1.0942 + 0.73443i\\r_5&=&\overline{r_4}\end{cases},$$

giving very different sidelengths, for example $\approx 1.73233$ between $r_1$ and $r_2$, and  $\approx 2.18836$ between $r_4$ and $\overline{r_4}$.

It is not centered in $0$ because the norms of the $r_k, k=1,\cdots 5$ are :

$$\approx 1.4519, 1.4082, 1.4082, 1.3178, 1.3178$$

---

**Edit :** A rigorous proof, by contradiction, can be given. Let us assume that the pentagon is regular *and* centered in the origin : this would mean that the roots, now with indices $k=0,\cdots 4$ would be :

$$r_k=re^{ik \tfrac{2 \pi}{5}}$$

where $r=r_0\ne 0$ is the unique real root.

Their product, using one of the Viète's formulas, would give rise to :

$$r^5\underbrace{e^{i (0+1+2+3+4) \tfrac{2\pi}{5}}}_{= \ 1}=-5\tag{2}$$

Plugging (2) into the following  relationship (true because $r$ is a root of equation (1)) :

$$r^5-r+5=0$$

leads to $r=0$ which is impossible.

As I know you are interested by Sage, here is the little program which has produced in particular the graphical representation :

> ```
> CC=ComplexField(20)
> p=x^5-x+5;
> s=p.roots(ring=CC);
> L=[];M=[];
> for k in range(len(s)):
>     m=s[k][0];
>     L.append([m.real(),m.imag()]);
>     M.append(abs(m));
> print(L);
> print(M);
> Q=points(L,size=50);
> show(Q,aspect_ratio=1);
> ```

Comment: Thank you again! It is very interesting to me that the roots do not form a regular pentagon, but how could we show it without approximations? Is there a way?

Comment: I just added a rigorous proof under the form of an Edit to my answer.

Comment: And for the case of a regular pentagon not necessarily centred at $0$, see my comment to the OP.

Comment: @JeanMarie You're amazing! Thank you!!

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks!! Do you know where can I find a proof of that result? I'm really interested.

Comment: @galoisman The roots of $z^n - 1$ are by definition the $n$'th roots of unity, which are $\exp(2 \pi i k/n)$ for $k = 0, 1, \ldots, n-1$ and form the vertices of a regular $n$-gon centred at $0$.  Scale and translate...

Comment: @RobertIsrael But why is $(x - a)^5 - b^5$ the unique polynomial with that property? By the way, what are $a, b$ exactly?

Comment: A monic polynomial is uniquely determined by its roots.